# Locate, extract and re-append year from column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've created a pandas dataframe using the 'read html' method from an external source. There's no problem creating the dataframe, however, I'm stuck trying to adjust the structure of the first column, 'Month'.

The data I'm scraping is updated once a month at the source, therefore, the solution requires a dynamic approach. So far I've only been able to achieve the desired outcome using .iloc to manually update each row, which works fine until the data is updated at source next month.

This is what my dataframe looks like:

```py
df = pd.read_html(url)
df
    Month           Value
0   2017            NaN
1   November        1.29
2   December        1.29
3   2018            NaN
4   January         1.29
5   February        1.29
6   March           1.29
7   April           1.29
8   May             1.29
9   June            1.28
10  July            1.28
11  August          1.28
12  September       1.28
13  October         1.26
14  November        1.16
15  December        1.09
16  2019            NaN
17  January         1.25
18  February        1.34
19  March           1.34
20  April           1.34
```

This is my desired outcome:

```py
df
    Month           Value
0   November 2017   1.29
2   December 2017   1.29
4   January 2018    1.29
5   February 2018   1.29
6   March 2018      1.29
7   April 2018      1.29
8   May 2018        1.29
9   June 2018       1.28
10  July 2018       1.28
11  August 2018     1.28
12  September 2018  1.28
13  October 2018    1.26
14  November 2018   1.16
15  December 2018   1.09
17  January 2019    1.25
18  February 2019   1.34
19  March 2019      1.34
20  April 2019      1.34
```

Right now the best idea I've come up with would be select, extract and append the year to each row in the 'Month' column, until the month 'December' is reached, and then switch to/increment to next year, but i have no idea how to implement this in code. Would this be a viable solution (and how could it be implemented?) or is there a better way?

Many thanks from a long time reader and first time poster of stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ffill` base on value, if it is `NaN` then we should forward fill the year here for  future paste

```
df.Month=df.Month+' '+df.Month.where(df.Value.isna()).ffill().astype(str)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df
Out[29]: 
             Month  Value
1    November 2017   1.29
2    December 2017   1.29
4     Januari 2018   1.29
5    Februari 2018   1.29
6        Mars 2018   1.29
7       April 2018   1.29
8         Maj 2018   1.29
9        Juni 2018   1.28
10       Juli 2018   1.28
11    Augusti 2018   1.28
12  September 2018   1.28
13    Oktober 2018   1.26
14   November 2018   1.16
15   December 2018   1.09
17    Januari 2019   1.25
18   Februari 2019   1.34
19       Mars 2019   1.34
20      April 2019   1.34
```

Comment: So hard to believe I ended up with the similar solution :0.

Comment: @BharathM nice to see you back

Comment: @salokin yw :-) happy coding